# alternative to display:none for mobile

Tags: php, html, css, mobile, responsive-design

Im currently building a practice responsive website, what I am doing is taking an exising website, building it up using twitter bootsrap js and css, meaning it will be fully responsive for mobile.

The issue is that there are some large carousels and images on the site. Ideally I would like to just completely remove certain elements, like a carousel for instance, and instead have the options within the carousel as a standard list menu.

It seems the main option is `display:none` based on media queries, but I am starting to foresee that I will run into big problems for loading time if the entire desktop site is still going to be loaded on the mobile, only elements hidden.

Are there ways to completely exclude html based on browser size? If anyone has any good links or articles that would be great. Or even just opinions, on whether there is actually need to exclude html or not.

Thank you

Comment: The only good way to do this that I can see is to serve different versions from server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off it is really good to see that although you're talking about `display:none;` you actually still want to display the content without the bells and whistles of the image.  Well done you.

The next thing I would look at is if you don't want to load images for a mobile then why are you adding it for the larger sites. If the image isn't providing a function, assisting in explaining the content better, then why not just drop it for the desktop size as well?

If in fact it does help tell a story then you can include the images and some of the popular image services like [adaptive images](http://adaptive-images.com/), [hiSRC](https://github.com/teleject/hisrc), or [PictureFill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill) which will serve the mobile version of the image first and replace with a larger image at higher viewports (but remember, there's no bandwidth test).

Finally, if you do want to serve some different content, then take the advice of fire around including more content with ajax.  The [South Street toolbox](https://github.com/filamentgroup/Southstreet) from Filament group can help you out, pay particular attention to the AjaxInclude pattern (it also has a link to the picturefill).

Comment: thanks for that, I think I will have to learn the ajax route as this could be an issue, not just with images, but with replacing entire elements with different elements. Regarding the images, cheers Ill have a look at those links and see how they work, as I think images are worth it for desktop and most people have a high enough broadband connection to handle them anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider storing heavy data JSON-encoded, and then creating elements and loading them on demand like so

```
var heavyImage = new Image();
heavyImage.src=imageList[id];
```

Then you can append image element to a desired block. From my experience with mobiles this is more robust than requesting `<img>` via AJAX, since AJAX could be pretty slow sometimes.

You may also 'prefetch' images with this method (like 2-3 adjacent to visible at the moment), thus improving UX.

Answer (score 1):

You could pull in the heavy elements via AJAX so they wouldn't sit on the page initially, making it load faster. You could decide to do the AJAX call only if the screen size is larger than X.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can use `visibility:hidden`, or if you use jQuery you can use

```
$(element).remove() //to remove completely
$(element).hide() //to hide 
$(element).fadeOut(1) //to fadeout
```

Comment: does it prevent the images from being loaded in the first place?

Comment: The img element has to be part of the DOM before it can be removed.  By the time it's there, the browser already knows to request the image.